# Problema con el uso de imágenes en React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Antes que nada soy nuevo en React y no entiendo porqué no me cargan las imágenes que tengo en una subcarpeta del proyecto. Copio la ruta entera de la imagen y tampoco tengo resultado:

```css
.header-upper-links img{

    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <header className='header-top-strip py-3'>
      <div className='col-5'>
             <div className='header-upper-links d-flex 
             align-items-center justify-content-between'>
              <div>
                <Link>
                  <img src='C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Proyectos REACT\e-commerce-nacho\src\imagenes\compare.png' alt='' />
                  <p></p>
                </Link>
               </div>
              </div>
       </div>
    </header>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Sin embargo si importo la imagen si me la carga: import Compare from '../imagenes/compare.png';
y luego en el src = {Compare} . Pero se me hace poco práctico utilizar este método porque son muchos íconos, productos, logos, etc.

Comment: De hecho la forma que comentas (usar el import) es lo recomendado para las imágenes :D

Comment: Una de las causas más comunes de este problema es que la ruta de la imagen no es válida. Al utilizar una ruta absoluta como la que estás utilizando, la aplicación tratará de cargar la imagen desde la raíz del sistema operativo, en lugar de desde la carpeta del proyecto. Para solucionar este problema, deberías utilizar una ruta relativa en lugar de una ruta absoluta. Esto significa que deberías proporcionar una ruta que indique la ubicación de la imagen en relación a la carpeta del proyecto, en lugar de proporcionar la ruta completa desde la raíz del sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, si la imagen

Comment: La ruta, mejor importa arriba por ejm `import imagen from '...'` y luego colocas la variable en el src

Comment: si pobre con una ruta relativa. Hice imagenes/compare.png pero tampoco funcionó, Si voy a importar las imágenes sólo pensé que quizás había otra forma más práctica. Igual gracias a todos por sus respuestas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mejor importa la imagen de esta forma.

***CODIGO***

```
import imagen from "../imagenes/Pac-Man_Cutscene.svg.png";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <img src={imagen} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***RESULTADO***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]